# IntelliJ - Android - reference external directory

Tags: android, intellij-idea, directory

I have several Android projects in IntelliJ that they all need reference the same directory. I don't know how to add that reference.

For example:

```
Project A
   |
   ---> Folder A
           |
           ---> Shared Folder
   ---> Folder X

Project B
   |
   ---> Folder B
           |
           ---> Shared Folder
   ---> Folder Y
```

I don't know how to add the reference to "Shared Folder". It's not a source folder... just a folder that contains images.

Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: Where do you want these images to be available in the final package? Assets, resources, classpath?

Comment: In assets folder. Actually, in my diagram "Folder A" and "Folder B" are "assets" folder for 2 separate projects.

Comment: Assets folder can be changed in the [Android Facet settings](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/5334/20121020225940.png).

Comment: I don't want to change it... just to add external folders/files to it from other locations (without copying them).

Comment: I don't think Android allows you to have multiple assets folders.

Comment: if its a static set of images you could compile it into a jar file and include that jar into all you projects

Comment: I can't compile to a jar. I just want several projects to have a "link" to a shared folder instead of copying it to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA you can have only one folder per module configured as **assets** folder.

A workaround could be to use multiple modules, where other modules will have additional assets folders and will be configured as **Is Library Project**. Your main module [can depend](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) on the other modules with their own assets.

Comment: I don't want multiple assets folders. I want one with linked subfolders.

Comment: It's essentially the same, you can combine subfolders of multiple modules into one assets folder, it's the only way to do it in IDEA.

Comment: What about eclipse? I tried to link folders there inside the assets folder and it also doesn't work.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, you may get another answer from Eclipse users, but I doubt that it's a common case when one needs to combine several directories into a single assets directory.

Comment: Thanks dude. I'll see what i'm doing with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when using libgdx with Idea. I wanted to share content of assets folder in android project between other non-android projects.

The only thing that worked for me was to create symbolic link in project B which was pointing to sub-folder of project A.